# Python code creates only three HTML pages

Tags: python, html

I have:

```
fruits = [ apple, pineapple, banana, oranges]
sizes = [ small, medium, large]
```

and for each fruit-size combination

```
( apple-small, apple-medium, pineapple-large etc.)
```

I have `fruitproperties = [color, size, weight]` 
each combination will have different description for color, size and may have new fruitproperties.

I am trying to create index page for this: 
Following is my python code:

```
def home(fruit):
    htmlfile = open('home.html', 'w')
    htmlfile.write = ("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
    htmlfile.write=("<html>\n")
    htmlfile.write=("<head>\n")
    htmfile.write = ("<title> Fruit-home page </title>\n") 
    htmlfile.write =("</head>\n")
    htmlfile.write = ("<body>\n")
    for fruit in fruits: 
        htmlfile.write=('<a href ="'+fruit+'.html"> The fruit list </a><br>\n')
    htmlfile.write = ("</body>\n")
    htmlfile.write = ("</html>\n")
```

Now for fruit.html I have following def

```
def fruit_pages(fruit)
    for fruit in fruits: 
        htmlfile = open(fruit+".html","w")
        htmlfile.write = ("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
        htmlfile.write=("<html>\n")
        htmlfile.write=("<head>\n")
        htmfile.write = ("<title> Individual page</title>\n") 
        htmlfile.write =("</head>\n")
        htmlfile.write = ("<body>\n")
# Problem is with following code 
            for fruit in fruits:
                for size in sizes:
                    htmlfile.write('<a href= "'+size+'.html">'+size+'</a><br>\n')
            htmlfile.write("</body>\n")
            htmlfile.write("</html>\n")
            htmlfile.close()
```

My above code creates only three html pages for size as

```
small.html, medium.html and large.html
```

and linked it for each fruit.html

since the information in each html will be different for each fruit. I want to create 3 html pages for each fruit. 
like

```
apple - apple_small.html, apple_medium.html, apple_large.html 
pineapple - pineapple_small.html, pineapple_medium.html, pineapple_large.html
```

and so on. and link it to respective fruit.html page.

```
#code for size.html 

def size_html(size)
    htmlfile = open(size+".html","w")
    htmlfile.write = ("<!DOCTYPE html>\n")
    htmlfile.write=("<html>\n")
    htmlfile.write=("<head>\n")
    htmfile.write = ("<title> size - fruit properties</title>\n") 
    htmlfile.write =("</head>\n")
    htmlfile.write = ("<body>\n")

    some code for linking it to individual fruitproperty.html pages         
    htmlfile.write("</body>\n")
    htmlfile.write("</html>\n")
    htmlfile.close()
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Are these `htmfile.write = ("<title> size - fruit properties</title>\n") ` typos?

Comment: This is the exact sort of situation where you want to use some sort of a template or better yet a full web framework that allows you to deal with url in a less ad-hoc manner.

Comment: What kind of framework can be used in Python?  I haven't done much html coding in python

Comment: Honestly I'd suggest [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) if the purpose is to serve webpages. It's fairly easy to use and overall it will be a whole lot easier than reinventing the wheel with URL management, templating, etc.